# How to implement RoR ActionCable in flutter web?

Tags: actioncable

How to implement RoR ActionCable in flutter web?
I had tried and implemented ActionCable in flutter and its working fine in Mobile devices but not working in Web

I had tried action_cable package in flutter. is there any other way to connect to RoR ActionCable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example